VScode activate python in powershell terminal and then execute line/selection in the same terminal
I recently reinstalled VScode and I am struggling with the following:
I have set the python.execSelectionInTerminal to Shift+Enter.
Afterwards, I open the default terminal (powershell) and then I activate python by running python in the shell.
My issue is that whenever I execute a line in the script that I have open using Shift+Enter even though I have an active python terminal open, VScode opens a new one. Is there any way to stop this?

This behaviour seems to be happening only for powershell. I use cmder and it behaves as expected. Could you try swapping to a different terminal and see if the behaviour is the same? If it is, pasting your settings might help.

VSC wants to know which terminal to send it to and what state it is in, it can do this by creating a new one and perform the needed setup

@NathanGavenski I tried it with CMD and I get the same outcome. Happy to paste my settings, I just dont know how to, so please let me know what other information might be helpful

@rioV8 fair, my question is can I somehow tell VScode that there is a perfectly good terminal with python already running and it could use that one?

@User2321, you can get the JSON file from it (a button on the top right of the settings allows you to do that).
